# Phalcon PhP - how to disable the main layout for an action

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm creating a action in one of my phalcon controller which will be used to generate a print version of a page. Here is my print.volt layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Print</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my view:

```
{% extends "layouts/print.volt" %}
{% block content %}
    HERE
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.print();
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

It is working, but my problem is that the content generated is inserted inside another layout that has the `{{ content() }}` tag. At the end O get a page with all the website menus, my print.volt and my view.  I would like to know how can I get just the view inserted inside the print.volt, without the master layout. How can I disable this behavior?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options come to mind.

1) Use Simple view, which can render a template without the layout:

```
$view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple();
$view->setViewsDir('PATH_TO_YOUR_VIEWS');
$html = $view->render('template-name', $params);
```

This option is also really handy when generating HTML for email sending.

2) Disable the layout for the current Controller::method

```
$this->view->setLayout('');
```

3) **Update:** [Timothy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497805/timothy) recommended an alternative to (2)

```
$this->view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
```

Comment: $this->view->setLayout(''); works for me, thanks! I will be voting the answer as correct< i just have to wait 10 minutes.

Comment: Wouldn't `$this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);` be a nicer solution?

Comment: Andre, perhaps you missed the namespace before View? Check option (3) above. @Timothy nice remark.

Comment: @Timothy Yeah, with the namespace it works, This also works $this->view->setLayout('print.volt');  Thanks guys!